# Why does live.com limit passwords to 16 characters?

Tags: microsoft

I wanted to register a @live.com e-mail address, but it says it can't register an e-mail address having a password that contains more than 16 chars.

Why? So that it would be easier to get the real password? (if the password hashes were stolen . . .)

Comment: I've seen this max limit of 16 chars on other sites too. If the password is stored hashed then it should be the same size in the database no matter what the real password is, so why limit? I hope it's not because they are storing the passwords unhashed and 16 chars is the size of the database field. I really hope not.

Comment: Bruteforceing a 16 char pass is more easy compared to brute-forcing a bigger one. (you know, there russian paying sites, those who specialize to brute-force hashes)

Comment: This is interesting: [IBM SQL & XML Data Limits](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0001029.html) The "Password access to a data source" row is 32 bytes maximum length which is the same size as a 16 character password after an MD5 hash is applied.

Comment: Rincewind42 and Dez bring up really intereseting points; neither of those possibilities are secure.

Comment: @Dez: Applying an MD5 to a 17 char password will still be 32 bytes. A more interesting point might be that 16 characters in Unicode would be 32 bytes.

Comment: @Dez why would the IBM DB2 specification be relevant when we're talking about live.com (Microsoft)?

Comment: @w0lf SQL DB usage

Comment: @Dez Could you elaborate?

Comment: @w0lf purely an assumption based on the link I gave in the comment about IBM SQL & XML Data limits. Specifically the row "Password to access a data source". I don't know SQL all that well (which is why I just gave an interesting source instead of calling it definitive) but it looks like there are maximum limits on a lot of field types, which could give someone enough info to give an answer on this question.

Comment: @Dez I think that's not possible, because Microsoft have their own DBMS (Sql Server) and they surely don't use IBM's. AFAIK, there is no hard 16 character limit in SQL Server for any type of column. It's also possible that they don't use a relational DB for this at all.

Comment: @w0lf like I said, just interesting and not definitive. Just sharing the link.

Comment: A fun fact: if you select the password field in the signup screen, a message appears to the right: "Strong passwords contain 7-16 characters [...]". Does that make a 20 char password weak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually because when you md5 a password it calculates a hash. Then the string is longer than 16 characters some "hashes" can collide between them.

For example if `md5("noroof")` gives `9ce405c98406f2f6d5326ee6b51d19cd` it is possible that `md5("ididntfixedmyroofwhenicould")` could give the same hash `9ce405c98406f2f6d5326ee6b51d19cd`. Remember that hashes are composed by with 32 characters of "0123456789abcdf" (for md5 in this case).

Maybe they force 16 character because the algorithm that computes the hash assures that will not have a collision in the database with a previously saved password.

Comment: A hash can always create a collision - as you say, it's possible that a 17+ character password would collide with a shorter password. 

But, it is just as unlikely to collide as a short password is unlikely to collide, and a long password is vanishingly unlikely to collide with a brute-force-guessable short password.

There's no reason to believe that long passwords are more likely to collide than short passwords - if there was some reason to believe that, the hash would be effectively broken anyway.

Comment: Ronald is correct, the accepted answer is plain wrong. The likelihood of MD5 strings to collide does not depend on their length.